# Every derived table must have its own alias mysql with temporary tables

Tags: mysql, select, derived-table

Could anyone be of help, as I don't see where this error message is coming from:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

In my point of view, I've added aliases to all tables?

```
SELECT ccdnormal.*
FROM card_call_detail AS ccdnormal
JOIN (

    SELECT ccd1.DB_CALL_ID
    FROM card_call_detail_tmp1 AS ccd1
    JOIN card_call_detail_tmp2 AS ccd2 ON ccd1.card_number = ccd2.card_number
    WHERE ccd1.start_time <> ccd2.start_time
      AND ccd1.end_time > ccd2.start_time
      AND ccd1.DB_CALL_ID <> ccd2.DB_CALL_ID
      AND ccd2.start_time BETWEEN ccd1.start_time AND ccd1.end_time

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ccd4.DB_CALL_ID
    FROM card_call_detail_tmp3 AS ccd3
    JOIN card_call_detail_tmp4 AS ccd4 ON ccd3.card_number = ccd4.card_number
    WHERE ccd3.start_time <> ccd4.start_time
      AND ccd3.end_time > ccd4.start_time
      AND ccd3.DB_CALL_ID <> ccd4.DB_CALL_ID
      AND ccd4.start_time BETWEEN ccd3.start_time AND ccd3.end_time )

) AS CCDOUTPUT ON CCDOUTPUT.DB_CALL_ID = ccdnormal.DB_CALL_ID
```

Comment: Random tip: add `()` around the unioned selects: `(SELECT ...) UNION ALL (SELECT ...)`

Comment: As shown, you have a syntax error since the parentheses don't balance.

Comment: @eggyal, what do you mean with this? biziclop his answer didn't help me...

Comment: @user1496811: You open one parenthesis `(` but close two parentheses `))`.

Comment: You where absolutely correct! That I didn't see it myself :S. Thank you so much!